# get back in dynamic html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i've index.html its continuing 3 div and any div continuing id for page working with jquery loading effect like dynamic website .. there is my code:

```
<div id="pagewrap" class="pagewrap">
    <div class="container show" id="page-1">
        <a href="#page-2" class="pageload-link">Start Ordering</a>
    </div>
```

```
    <div class="container" id="page-2">
        <li class="soups">
            <a href="#page-3" class="pageload-link">
                <div class="links">Soups</div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <p><a class="pageload-link" id="back" href="#page-1">Go back button</a></p>
    </div>
```

```
    <div class="container" id="page-3">
        <p><a class="pageload-link" id="back" href="#page-1">Go back button</a></p>
    </div>
```

```
</div>
```

there is an example in index.html working with jquery page loading effects

Here is my script:

```
(function () {
    var pageWrap = document.getElementById('pagewrap'),
        pages = [].slice.call(pageWrap.querySelectorAll('div.container')),
        currentPage = 0,
        triggerLoading = [].slice.call(pageWrap.querySelectorAll('a.pageload-link')),
        loader = new SVGLoader(document.getElementById('loader'), {
            speedIn: 300,
            easingIn: mina.easeinout
        });

    function init() {
        triggerLoading.forEach(function (trigger) {
            trigger.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
                ev.preventDefault();
                loader.show();

                // after some time hide loader
                setTimeout(function () {
                    loader.hide();
                    classie.removeClass(pages[currentPage], 'show');

                    // update..
                    currentPage = currentPage ? 0 : 1;
                    classie.addClass(pages[currentPage], 'show');
                }, 2000);

                setTimeout(function () {
                    loader.hide();
                    classie.removeClass(pages[currentPage], 'show');

                    // update..
                    currentPage = currentPage ? 1 : 2;
                    classie.addClass(pages[currentPage], 'show');
                }, 2000);
            });
        });
    }
    init();
})();
```

my problem here when i try to click go back button its showing page with id page-3 only in all three divs (go back button its not working correctly).. so i need when i'm on page with id page-3 (the third page) and i click to go back button its working back to page with id page-2 (the second page)... and when i'm on page with id page-2 (the second page) and i click to go back button its working back to page with id page-1 (the first page)...
i hope to found the fix 
best regards..

Comment: Peter, in future please try and format your code properly (an empty line before and after your code, and indent each line by four, or more, spaces, and remove extraneous lines of white-space). @Rory: thank you, I was just about to paste in my own edits for that code :)

Comment: @Salketer Not everyone on SO is a native speaker.

Comment: @Salketer nazis raus !

Comment: thanks for answer,  i've  been edited my query.. is that fine

Comment: no one answer me right now